# How to set parameter authCode with Microsoft Graph SDK in PHP?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I need, through PHP, to recover calendars from an Outlook organization. Reading the documentation of Microsoft Graph SDK (version 2.3.0), I need to use the me() function, so I need an authorization code. How can I recover this? I need it to then pass it as a parameter to the instance of the AuthorizationCodeContext object.

```
<?php 
use Microsoft\Graph\GraphServiceClient;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Abstractions\ApiException;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Authentication\Oauth\AuthorizationCodeContext;

// Values from app registration
    $clientId = 'xxxxxxx';
    $tenantId = 'xxxxxxx';
    $clientSecret = 'xxxxx';
    $redirectUri = 'https://www.example.org/oauth/';

    $tokenRequestContext = new AuthorizationCodeContext(
        $tenantId,
        $clientId,
        $clientSecret,
        $authCode,
        $redirectUri
    );
    $scopes = ['User.Read'];
    $graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext, $scopes);
```

I have already set the appropriate configurations in Microsoft Login ID and enabled permissions, but I don't understand how to recover this parameter `$authCode`.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php?tab=readme-ov-file#create-a-token-request-context: _"Note that your application will need to handle redirecting the user to the Microsoft Identity login page to get the authorization_code that's passed into the AuthorizationCodeContext. [See](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) for more on the authorization_code grant flow."_

Comment: @CBroe There is no example code written for how to achieve this in PHP in this documentation

Comment: Can't tell right now, whether that SDK comes with a method to create the authorization request URL. But simply building the URL as shown under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#authorization-request, can't be that hard to do yourself either, can it?